# How to show the contents of a list?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my application I get some data from server and show this into my `recyclerView`.
I want show all of list content **not show** just item 0.

**My adapter codes:**

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Post> postList;
private Context context;
private ListItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public PostsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> allPostList) {
    this.context = context;
    postList = allPostList;
}

public void setItemClickListener(ListItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view, viewType, itemClickListener);
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView imgPost;
    private TextView tvPostTitle, tvPostCategory, tvPostDate;
    private CardView mCardView;
    private ListItemClickListener itemClickListener;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType, ListItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(itemView);

        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        // Find all views ids
        imgPost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_img);
        tvPostTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        tvPostCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_category);
        tvPostDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
        mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_top);

        mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (itemClickListener != null) {
            itemClickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), view);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != postList ? postList.size() : 0);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostsAdapter.ViewHolder mainHolder, int position) {
    final Post model = postList.get(position);

    // setting data over views
    String title = model.getTitle().getRendered();
    mainHolder.tvPostTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));

    String imgUrl = null;
    if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().size() > 0) {
        if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails() != null) {
            if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl() != null) {
                imgUrl = model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl();
            }
        }
    }

    if (imgUrl != null) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imgUrl)
                .into(mainHolder.imgPost);
    } else {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(R.color.imgPlaceholder)
                .into(mainHolder.imgPost);
    }

    String category = null;

    if (model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().size() >= 1) {
        category = model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().get(0).get(0).getName();
    }
    if (category == null) {
        category = context.getResources().getString(R.string.default_str);
    }
    mainHolder.tvPostCategory.setText(Html.fromHtml(category));
    mainHolder.tvPostDate.setText(model.getFormattedDate());
}
}
```

but in above code just show me item 0 , but **I want show all of items**.

how can I it?

Comment: category = model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().get(i).get(i).getName();  where i is a loop varialbe.

Comment: can you post your code please ?

Comment: post some extra code. in your line showing 0 instead of position, that means only 1 item

Comment: @Lucifer, please see my update code

Comment: @srinu, please see my update codes

Comment: @RedBounce, try get(position), very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().get(i).size();j++){

            Log.e("DATA",model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().get(i).get(j).getName());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String category = "";
for(int i=0; response.size();i++){
{
category = category + "," +  model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().get(i).get(i).getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `recyclerview` , its adapter has `onBindViewHolder()` method , which gives you a **position** variable. Use that to iterate through the list!

```
model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(position).getMediaDetails()
```